# What's the meaning of "Bought it up"

Tags: american-english, informal-language

I heard this phrase from a TV show.

> We thought you bought it up there.

The background is that Mike who is injured in an accident and come back to his friends, one of them said "we thought you bought it up there". I guess it means you're dead or similar, but I need confirm on it. While google says bought it up means buy sth in large amount is definetely not the correct answer I am looking for..Thanks for clarification.

Comment: *bought it* is a shortened form of [*bought the big one*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buy+the+big+one)

Comment: What's the purpose of pasting an image with the text?

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse "bought it up" with "bought it" - they are entirely different idioms.

Your reference is to **"bought it"** which is an idiom meaning 'to die'; frequently used in war films, etc.
There's an invisible comma separating the ideas.

> We thought you bought it, up there.

There's a long version - 'to have bought the farm' - though I don't know which came first, or if one is a short form of the other, or one is a long form...

There's an additional meaning, which you would have to extract from context, "bought it" can also mean to believe something.

> I told him the lie & he bought it.

By extension, there's a movie term meaning to accept that take [current version of the scene being filmed] & be moving on to the next setup.

> Did they like the take?
>   Yeah, they bought it, we're moving on.

**"Bought it up"** however, really does mean 'to purchase', though it hints towards 'all' of something.

> Are they really building a motorway where your street is?
>   Yeah, the government bought it up.

The government bought the entire street & surrounding land.

Comment: Let's not forget that if someone tells a lie and you "buy it", it means you're believing it.

Comment: yeah - I was trying to avoid the confusion.. there's also the movie term, if they 'buy it' it means they liked the take & are moving on to the next shot.

Comment: @ChatterOne - added.

Answer (score 1):

To "buy it" can be used idiomatically to mean die, or be killed